# Select Option Not Accepting a PHP as Value

Tags: php, html

I am returning a value that is currently in the database, and interval day right now equals to 5 when I echo it out.

Now when I input it inside my option form it will always return '0'.

```
  <?php $interval_day = $this->crud_model->auto_order_interval_day(); ?>
    Interval Day:   <select name="interval_day">
    <option value="<?php echo $interval_day ?>" selected disabled><?php echo $interval_day ?></option>
<option value='1'>1</option>
```

Pretty much I want the number currently in the database to be selected incase they don't change this value.

Comment: Put a semicolon `;` after your statement. - `<?php echo $interval_day; ?>`

Comment: still nothing,,

Comment: Please provide us with more information on what you want to achieve and what the data source looks like. Doing it like this will likely break your options in case of duplicate values, and also render the "disabled" attribute useless, because the user could just select the value in the options appended below the first entry.

Comment: That if a user clicks submit on the form and doesn't want to change the interval day it will automatically stay the same, hence why I wanted to echo the interval day value into the select statement as first one.

Comment: Also `disabled` form fields do not return a value. Use `readonly` instead if you want to block user's input and it should be on the `select` tag, not the `option`.

Comment: You do not have to post it as the first option value to have it appear first. The selected option will always be focused on form load.

Comment: @TodorSimeonov Thank you it worked.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how I would go about it.
If you have a select whose options are populated from a database source, I would expect to build it something like this:

```
$interval_day = $this->crud_model->auto_order_interval_day();

foreach ($interval_days as $day) {
  echo "<option value=\"$day\" ". ($interval_day === $day ? "selected disabled" : "") . ">$day</option>\n";
}
```

If you do it like you do it in your code sample, what happens if `$interval_day` is 1? Then you have a duplicate option value for interval_day 1...

Comment: Theres only one value for interval day in the database per user. This wouldn't be helpful

Comment: You have a select field if there's only one value? What's the point in that?

Comment: Theres 30 values I just put this as an example

Comment: If I understand you right, there is 30 values to choose from, and there can only be one of the values assigned per user? So that's exactly that the code above is useful for. `$interval_days` is your iterator (an array) with all 30 values in it in that case. Just initialize the that variable with those values and it will work out of the box.

Comment: No, interval day is one value in the database and can only be one value. This form is based on an update

Comment: So again: if there is only one value to display inside the select, why use a select?